# In columns containining 'X', check for and delete rows containing 'Y'

Tags: python, pandas

Say I want to delete rows where any cell, which is in a column whose title contains 'X', contains the word 'acme'. My current thinking is to add a for loop (for column titles containing X), then use a previously defined mask to remove 'acme' rows. Is there a better way?

Also, some help on masks/querying would be appreciated, since I have never used them.

Input DF:

```
Company_x   First Name  Last Name   Emails_x    Created_x   Hosted Meetings 03112016    Facilitated Meetings_x  Attended Meetings_x Company_y   Emails_y    ... Created_x   Hosted Meetings 04122016    Facilitated Meetings_x  Attended Meetings_x Company_y   Emails_y    Created_y   Hosted Meetings 04212016    Facilitated Meetings_y  Attended Meetings_y
0   TS  X Y X@Y.com 03/10/2016  0.0 0.0 0.0 TS  X@Y.com ... 03/10/2016  0.0 0.0 2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   TS  X Y X@Y.com 03/10/2016  0.0 0.0 0.0 TS  X@Y.com ... 01/25/2016  0.0 0.0 0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   TS  X Y X@Y.com 03/10/2016  0.0 0.0 0.0 TS  X@Y.com ... 04/06/2015  9.0 10.0    17.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis with
all_users_sheets_hosts.filter(like='Company')

Comment: Try always to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. In case of _pandas_ questions please provide sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format _as text_, so one could use it when coding an answer for you). This will help to avoid _situations_ like: `your code isn't working for me` or `it doesn't work with my data`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Edited my question with the first three rows of the dataframe and the error and where it occurs

Comment: you've got got plenty of duplicated columns (same column names) - how can you work with this DF???

Comment: Good point. I looked for a different way to go about things and have asked a new question about dropping NaN rows in the final file in a for loop loading in excel files, and dropping many of the duplicated columns from all but the final loaded in excel file

Comment: [Dropping NaN rows, certain columns in specific excel files using glob/merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944960/dropping-nan-rows-certain-columns-in-specific-excel-files-using-glob-merge)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
In [150]: df
Out[150]:
      A    AXA      X   ZXZ  ZZNX
0  acme    axa  pacme   aaa     1
1  meca      A   BZZZ   ccc     2
2   YYY      a      c    me     3
3   000  macme    111  2222     4

In [151]: df[(df.filter(like='X').astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('acme')))
   .....:    .sum(axis=1)==0
   .....:   ]

Out[151]:
      A AXA     X  ZXZ  ZZNX
1  meca   A  BZZZ  ccc     2
2   YYY   a     c   me     3
```

Explanation:

using `filter()` we can filter columns, containing `X`:

```
In [152]: df.filter(like='X')
Out[152]:
     AXA      X   ZXZ  ZZNX
0    axa  pacme   aaa     1
1      A   BZZZ   ccc     2
2      a      c    me     3
3  macme    111  2222     4
```

search for cells containing `acme` - column-by-column, using `apply()` function

```
In [153]: df.filter(like='X').astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('acme'))
Out[153]:
     AXA      X    ZXZ   ZZNX
0  False   True  False  False
1  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
3   True  False  False  False
```

In Python: `True == 1`, `False ==0`, so summing cells in each row `sum(axis=1)` will give us `1` for rows where at least one cell contains our search word and `0` - elsewhere:

```
In [154]: (df.filter(like='X').astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('acme'))).sum(axis=1)
Out[154]:
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I get 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis' because of the filter...

Comment: @FredericBastiat, can you post a data set which would help to reproduce your error?

Comment: It's kind of a mess to post in a comment here. I'll describe it where you may be able to ID potential problems. The Company columns will all have the same values within a row. Many rows have NaN values (potentially also in the Company column). Many Company columns have the same name (There are only Company columns named Company_y and Company_x). There are many other (but not all) columns named similarly (e.g. meetings_x and meetings_y)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[11,'acme'],[22,'samme'],[33,'mamme']],columns=('SI','X'))
bool_arr = ~df.X.str.contains('acme')
df1 = df[bool_arr]
print df1
```

You can now use df1 to do save/other operations.