# Dropping NaN rows, certain columns in specific excel files using glob/merge

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I would like to drop NaN rows in the final file in a for loop loading in excel files, and dropping all company, emails, created duplicated columns from all but the final loaded in excel file.

Here is my for loop (and subsequent merging into a single DF), currently:

```
for f in glob.glob("./gowall-users-export-*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_users_sheets_hosts.append(df)
    j = re.search('(\d+)', f)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.*Hosted Meetings.*', 'Hosted Meetings' + ' ' + j.group(1))

all_users_sheets_hosts = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['First Name', 'Last Name'], how='outer'), all_users_sheets_hosts)
```

Here are the first few rows of the resulting DF:

```
Company_x   First Name  Last Name   Emails_x    Created_x   Hosted Meetings 03112016    Facilitated Meetings_x  Attended Meetings_x Company_y   Emails_y    ... Created_x   Hosted Meetings 04122016    Facilitated Meetings_x  Attended Meetings_x Company_y   Emails_y    Created_y   Hosted Meetings 04212016    Facilitated Meetings_y  Attended Meetings_y
0   TS  X Y X@Y.com 03/10/2016  0.0 0.0 0.0 TS  X@Y.com ... 03/10/2016  0.0 0.0 2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   TS  X Y X@Y.com 03/10/2016  0.0 0.0 0.0 TS  X@Y.com ... 01/25/2016  0.0 0.0 0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   TS  X Y X@Y.com 03/10/2016  0.0 0.0 0.0 TS  X@Y.com ... 04/06/2015  9.0 10.0    17.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: What constitutes a NaN row? Is it a row where *any* value is NaN? or a row where *all* values are NaN? or...?

Comment: In this case, a row with any NaN values will have all NaN values, so it doesn't make a difference. I should have mentioned that, though.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent multiple `Company`, `Emails`, `Created`, `Facilitated Meetings` and `Attended Meetings` columns, drop them from the `right` DataFrame. To remove rows with all `NaN` values, use `result.dropna(how='all', axis=0)`:

```
import pandas as pd
import functools

for f in glob.glob("./gowall-users-export-*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_users_sheets_hosts.append(df)
    j = re.search('(\d+)', f)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.*Hosted Meetings.*', 
                                        'Hosted Meetings' + ' ' + j.group(1))

# Drop rows of all NaNs from the final DataFrame in `all_users_sheets_hosts`
all_users_sheets_hosts[-1] = all_users_sheets_hosts[-1].dropna(how='all', axis=0)

def mergefunc(left, right):
    cols = ['Company', 'Emails', 'Created', 'Facilitated Meetings', 'Attended Meetings']
    right = right.drop(cols, axis=1)
    result = pd.merge(left, right, on=['First Name', 'Last Name'], how='outer')
    return result

all_users_sheets_hosts = functools.reduce(mergefunc, all_users_sheets_hosts)
```

Since the `Company` et. al. columns will only exist in the `left` DataFrame, there will be no proliferation of those columns. Note, however, that if the `left` and `right` DataFrames have different values in those columns, only the values in the first DataFrame in `all_users_sheets_hosts` will be kept.

---

Alternative, if the `left` and `right` DataFrames have the same values for the `Company` et. al. columns, then another option would be to simple merge on those columns too:

```
def mergefunc(left, right):
    cols = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Company', 'Emails', 'Created', 
            'Facilitated Meetings', 'Attended Meetings']
    result = pd.merge(left, right, on=cols, how='outer')
    return result
all_users_sheets_hosts = functools.reduce(mergefunc, all_users_sheets_hosts)
```

Comment: thank you very much. I've used your first proposal with success, however, the row dropping is not quite what I wanted. With the code you gave me, it tries to drop rows that are all (or any) Na in the whole, merged dataframe. I would like to consider Na rows only in the last merged file of the dataframe

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your question more carefully. `all_users_sheets_hosts[-1] = all_users_sheets_hosts[-1].dropna(how='all', axis=0)` will drop the empty (NaN) rows from the *last* DataFrame in `all_users_sheets_hosts` only.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work, and I've played around with it a bit. Wouldn't all_users_sheets_hosts[-1] be the last column of all_users_sheets_hosts? Even so, it is not deleting the rows that are na in that last column...

Comment: Immediately after the `for f in glob.glob` loop, `all_users_sheets_hosts` is a list. So `all_users_sheets_hosts[-1]` refers to the last item in the list. Since DataFrames were appended to this list in the `for-loop`, `all_users_sheets_hosts[-1]` should be a DataFrame.

Comment: If you are still having trouble, try to prepare a small runnable example which demonstrates the problem. Given a DataFrame, printing `df.head().reset_index().to_dict('list')` and `df.info()` can be very helpful for us so that we can reconstruct the situation you are dealing with. If the data is private, simply modify the quantitative values while leaving it qualitatively the same.